# Decode email subject string in base64 and utf-8

Tags: java, email, utf-8, base64, encode

My course homework is an email client, I used pop3 to get a email String like :

> Subject: =?UTF-8?B?6L+Z5piv5Li76aKY?=

Then I used a regexp to fetch  *6L+Z5piv5Li76aKY* , decode it with Base64 , and my Eclipse workspace is UTF-8. It shows like : *���L_���/�y�+�..�*, but it's originally Chinese *这是主题*

How can I show it properly? The content of email works well, and it's encoded with Base64 and UTF-8 as well, but the subject can't work.

Here is the code

```
if (buf.startsWith("Subject:")) {

    String regex = "=\\?UTF-8\\?B\\?(.*)\\?=";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(buf);
    while (m.find()) {
        subject = MyBase64.getFromBASE64(m.group(1));
    }

    subject = MyBase64.getFromBASE64(buf.substring(8));
    System.out.println(subject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , my method is right.
And I just made a stupid mistake ~  sorry  :D

Comment: Perhaps you could share your fix?